# Appending foreach values to list of sametype C#

Tags: c#

In below code, I'm returning each issue details in foreach loop and I have around 150 issues.Eachtime i loop through I'm getting the last values in "returnResulttoReport".
Note: "result" is a JSON string and foreach is getting result as below:

Here is my issue class:

```
    [DataContract]
public class MyIssues
{
    public MyIssues()
    {
        Comments = new List<Comment>();

    }

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Key;

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public List<Comment> Comments;
}


[DataContract]
public class Comment
{

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime? Updated;


}

public List<MyIssues> method(string result)
{
    RootObject myresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    List<MyIssues> returnResulttoReport = new List<MyIssues>();
    foreach (var item in myresult.issues)
    {
        issueKey = item.key ?? string.Empty;
        foreach (var commentitem in item.fields.comment.comments)
        {
            updated = commentitem.updated ?? string.Empty;
        }
    }

    MyIssues temp1 = new MyIssues{ Comments = new List<Comment>
           {
            new Comment() { 
                Updated = updated
                 }
           },
             Key = key };
    returnResulttoReport.Add(temp1);
    return returnResulttoReport;
}
```

Basically, I wanted to capture each return result before it get lost.

I tried putting it in ArrayList like below:

```
 ArrayList<JiraIssues> sendAllForReport = new ArrayList<JiraIssues>();
```

I'm getting error: The generic type arraylist can not be used with type arguments. How to resolve this? Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Your code example is too heavily redacted.  For example, where is `updated` declared, and where is its value used?

Comment: Modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are reassigning `updated` without ever reading its value until you finish the loop.  Therefore, the last item in the loop is the only one you read.  You need to add an item to the list for each iteration in the loop, so the code to do that must be inside the loop rather than after it.  Try this instead:

```
public List<MyIssues> method(string result)
{
    RootObject myresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    List<MyIssues> returnResulttoReport = new List<MyIssues>();
    foreach (var item in myresult.issues)
    {
        issueKey = item.key ?? string.Empty;
        foreach (var commentitem in item.fields.comment.comments)
        {
            updated = commentitem.updated ?? string.Empty;

            MyIssues temp1 = new MyIssues {
                Comments = new List<Comment>
                    {
                        new Comment() { Updated = updated }
                    },
                Key = key };
            returnResulttoReport.Add(temp1);
        }
    }
    return returnResulttoReport;
}
```

The fact that `updated` is declared somewhere else is a terrible code smell.  I would do this instead:

```
public List<MyIssues> method(string result)
{
    RootObject myresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
    List<MyIssues> returnResulttoReport = new List<MyIssues>();
    foreach (var item in myresult.issues)
    {
        issueKey = item.key ?? string.Empty;
        foreach (var commentitem in item.fields.comment.comments)
        {
            var upd = commentitem.updated ?? string.Empty;

            MyIssues temp1 = new MyIssues {
                Comments = new List<Comment>
                    {
                        new Comment() { Updated = upd }
                    },
                Key = key };
            returnResulttoReport.Add(temp1);
        }
    }
    return returnResulttoReport;
}
```

(I called the variable `upd` so it would not conflict with other possible uses of `updated` in some other scope.)

Comment: Do you think, I have to assign the values to outer for each loop? as key I'm getting form outer for each.

Comment: @TryingBest I don't quite understand your comment.  The object you're creating has one property that is assigned from the inner loop and one that is assigned from the outer loop.  But I do not understand what "assign the values to outer for each loop" means.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the type [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - C#'s [`ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a generic type. It's a holdover from the days before generics in .NET.